# Are WOT/SOT topologies hereditarily separable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Just out of curiosity,

> Are weak and strong operator topologies on $B(H)$ hereditarily separable?

In other words, if $S$ is a subset of $B(H)$, where $H$ is a separable Hilbert space, is $S$ separable in the relative WOT/SOT topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Ernest Michael shows in [On a theorem of Rudin and Klee](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1961-0133108-4), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 12 (1961), 921 that the space $Y^X$ of continuous functions $X\to Y$ between second countable spaces is hereditarily separable in the topology of pointwise convergence and also in the compact-open topology. His argument is beautiful and short -- the article is half a page long.

Since the strong operator topology on $B(H)$ is the subspace topology induced by $H^H$ with the topology of pointwise convergence, it follows that $B(H)$ with the strong operator topology is hereditarily separable. Since the weak operator topology is weaker, it is also hereditarily separable.